# Replace cid with proper image URL in gmail body content

Tags: gmail-imap

I am working on [AE.Net.Mail](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail)
How can I replace cid with its proper image in gmail html content body received through imap
For example:

```
<img width=167 height=238 id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01CF2E49.AFD81CE0">
```

the above code results in broken images. The image `src` suppose to hold proper image address. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That SRC value is pointing to an embedded body part with a content-id of image001.png@01CF2E49.AFD81CE0

You need to verify that part exists in your email.